# Add subheader to a list but only once

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, date-fns

I need to add a subheader to a list. Currently every entry with a date that is today gets a subheader but I only want to set it once. The problem seems to be that I can't access the updated value of `todaySubheader` inside the `<span v-if="todaySubheader`.

HTML

```
<template v-for="(meetup, index) in filteredItems">
            <v-subheader
              v-if="checkIsToday(meetup.date)"
              inset
            >
            <span v-if="todaySubheader === false">TODAY</span>
            </v-subheader>
```

SCRIPT

```
data () {
    return {
      todaySubheader: false,
[...]
checkIsToday (val) {
  if (val && this.todaySubheader === false) {
    this.todaySubheader = true
  }
  return isToday(new Date(val))
},
```

How to access the changed value of **this.todaySubheader** in **v-if="todaySubheader**?

Comment: I tried to answer (better formatting in answer section), but maybe you could provide more info? For example I don't understand why you have two `v-if`s there? Can you  reproduce minimal example on codepen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do access `todaySubheader`, but you don't want to do that because you change it multiple times in that `v-for` when you call the function. You might want to get index of the first `today` meetup:

```
<v-subheader v-if="index === todayIndex"
...
computed: {
  todayIndex() {
    return this.filteredItems.findIndex(v => isToday(new Date(v.date) ) )
  },
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I get multiple subheader instead of only one per day. Any ideas?

Comment: Do multiple meetups have today's date in `meetup.date`? Basically hard to know unless you reproduce minimal working example, but I think my suggestion should work, unless I misunderstood what your goal is.

Comment: Yes, multiple meetups have the same date.

Comment: @Tom Edited, but only for case of `today` (if you need only one subheader). If you need multiple subheaders then we are going to need more editing.

Comment: That worked great for the _isToday_ and _isTomorrow_ requests that are integrated in _Date-FNS_ lib. How to make it work with calling a **custom function** like             `<v-subheader v-if="isDayAfterTomorrowIndex(event.date)">Day after tomorrow</v-subheader>`? I get the error message **isDayAfterTomorrowIndex is not a function**

Answer (score 1):

you could create a global javascript variable:

```
var todayAdded=false;
```

then your checkToday method will the following:

```
checkIsToday (val) {
  if (isToday(new Date(val))) {
    if (!todayAdded)
       todayAdded= true;
    return true;
  }
  return false;  
},
```

and your html:

```
<template v-for="(meetup, index) in filteredItems">
            <v-subheader
              v-if="checkIsToday(meetup.date)">
            <span v-if="!todayAdded">TODAY</span>
            </v-subheader>
```

Comment: This can not possibly work mainly because you try to use global variable in vue template. But even if you fix your answer with that regard, I fail to notice how it's different than the OP's attempt?